# optirun - Cannot access secondary GPU - error: [XORG] (EE) NOUVEAU(0): [drm] failed to set drm interface version

Tags: graphics-card, gpu, nvidia-geforce, wine, manjaro

I'm trying to use my GPU with the game Counter-Strike 1.6 using Wine on Manjaro (Linux).

**The following error occurs:**

```
Cannot access secondary GPU - error: [XORG] (EE) NOUVEAU(0): [drm] failed to set drm interface version.
```

**Command:**

```
optirun wine hl.exe -- hl.exe -console -game cstrike -full -noipx -toconsole +connect
```

**GPU model:**

```
NVIDIA Corporation GF108M [GeForce GT 630M]
```

**NOTE I:** It's an NVIDIA with Optimus technology.
**NOTE II:** The driver in use is "video-hybrid-intel-nouveau-bumblebee".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To the failure below...

```
Cannot access secondary GPU - error: [XORG] (EE) NOUVEAU(0): [drm] failed to set drm interface version.
```

...  does not happen anymore do the following.

**Remove the bumblebee and its dependencies:**

Remove the bumblebee and video-hybrid-intel-nouveau-bumblebee to avoid the failure...

```
Error: config 'video-hybrid-intel-nvidia-bumblebee' conflicts with config(s): video-hybrid-intel-nouveau-bumblebee
```

... when trying to run the command "mhwd -a pci nonfree 0300 -f".

```
pacman -Rdcs bumblebee
mhwd -r pci video-hybrid-intel-nouveau-bumblebee
```

**Install the most suitable proprietary driver for your GPU:**

```
mhwd -a pci nonfree 0300 -f
```

NOTE: The above command will automatically install the best driver for your GPU.

**To test:**

```
vblank_mode=0 primusrun glxgears -info
```

If all goes well something like this will be displayed:

```
GL_RENDERER   = GeForce GT 630M/PCIe/SSE2
```

NOTE I: The option "vblank_mode = 0" is only for "benchmark" purpose, that is, for the GPU run with all its power. In normal execution this is not necessary unless you want to waste GPU processing power and electrical power.
NOTE II: optirun is deprecated, use primusrun instead.

**Primus bridge:**

In general, using the primus bridge gives better performance then using the default VirtualGL bridge (optirun). In bumblebee 4.0 (coming soon) primus will become the default bridge and VirtuaGL will need to be called explicitly if you still want it. Also beginning with bumblebee 4.0 (coming soon) the VirtuaGL dependency will be replaced with a primus dependency instead. So you might not even have VirtuaGL installed by default in the future.

So I recommend set Bridge=primus in /etc/bumblebee/bumblebee.conf. In this way you won't have to specify it on the command line ("optirun -b primus").

NOTE: By now primusrun do not accept options as optirun does. Setting primus as the bridge for optirun provides more flexibility.

**TIP:**

To check which GPUs are available on Manjaro (Linux) type...

```
lspci | egrep "(VGA|3D)"
```

**REFERENCES:**

https://forum.manjaro.org/t/newbie-questions-about-hybrid-nvidia-and-intel-gpu-drives-tutorial/2974/27
https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/bumblebee
https://www.linux.org.ru/forum/desktop/11142476
http://www.manjaro.fr/forum/viewtopic.php?t=6445&p=78191
https://forum.archlinux-br.org/viewtopic.php?id=4644
http://manjaro-linux.com.br/forum/dicas-truques/alternar-entre-nvidia-ou-nouveau-optimus-com-mhwd-t1160.html

### https://classicforum.manjaro.org/index.php?topic=3385.0

**NOTE:**
This thread was originally created by me in...
[optirun - Cannot access secondary GPU - error: [XORG] (EE) NOUVEAU(0): [drm] failed to set drm interface version](https://superuser.com/questions/1166129/optirun-cannot-access-secondary-gpu-error-xorg-ee-nouveau0-drm-fai)
I just transposed it to the official Manjaro forum